# Lazy column items not showing in release mode

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have an application written in kotlin, jetpack compose.
I have some items that I get from network and show in a lazy column.
Now the problem is that when I build in debug mode, the data is laggy but it is shown.
When I build a signed apk in release mode, every thing is smooth, but the lazyColumn is not shown.

Comment: Is minify enabled in build.gradle release block and are you using Retrofit for network?

Comment: Do you see anything in the logs? Also, sharing some code might help us understand what is going on.

Comment: @AtickFaisal Yes. minify is enabled and I'm using Retrofit

Comment: @tomerpacific No nothing useful is shown in the logs.

Comment: Most likely your data classes are getting scrambled by R8 minify.  Add [this](https://github.com/square/retrofit/blob/trunk/retrofit/src/main/resources/META-INF/proguard/retrofit2.pro) you your proguard rules. Also make sure you [add your retrofit data classes](https://g.co/gemini/share/f3b5663cf3db) to progurad.

Comment: @AtickFaisal
That worked. Thank you for you help. If you want, you can answer and I'll hit the tick on your answer.

Comment: If you're using Moshi and you've properly annotated the properties/fields with `@Json(name = "")` and annotated classes with `@JsonClass(generatedAdapter = true)` then you don't need to add all those rules.

Comment: @ArmanTabibZadeh great to hear that. Also what @Abbas said. No need to use proguard rules if you use propoer annotations like `@SerializedName` for gson and the one mentioned for moshi.